# shows mysql records twice because of inner joining

Tags: mysql, sql

In below query (Mentors) are 13 which shows me 26, while (SchoolSupervisor) are 5 which shows me 10 which is wrong. it is because of the Evidence which having 2 evidance, because of 2 evidence the Mentors & SchoolSupervisor values shows me double. 
please help me out.

Query:

```
select t.c_id,t.province,t.district,t.cohort,t.duration,t.venue,t.v_date,t.review_level, t.activity, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN pr.p_association = "Mentor" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Mentor, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN pr.p_association = "School Supervisor" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SchoolSupervisor,
        (CASE WHEN count(file_id) > 0 THEN "Yes" ELSE "No" END) as evidence
        FROM review_m t , review_attndnce ra 
        LEFT JOIN participant_registration AS pr ON pr.p_id = ra.p_id 
        LEFT JOIN review_files AS rf ON rf.training_id  = ra.c_id
        WHERE 1=1 AND t.c_id = ra.c_id
        group by t.c_id, ra.c_id order by t.c_id desc
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GabI.png)

Comment: Wrap it with a distinct query

Comment: @MASh i tried distinct before rf.file_id but unlucky.

Comment: I guess it should be - distinct t.c_id.

Comment: Don't mix explicit and implicit, comma separated joins... Just too confusing. Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may perform the aggregations in a separate subquery, and then join to it:

```
SELECT
    t.c_id,
    t.province,
    t.district,
    t.cohort,
    t.duration,
    t.venue,
    t.v_date,
    t.review_level,
    t.activity,
    pr.Mentor,
    pr.SchoolSupervisor,
    rf.evidence
FROM review_m t
INNER JOIN review_attndnce ra
    ON t.c_id = ra.c_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        p_id,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN p_association = 'Mentor' THEN 1 END) AS Mentor,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN p_association = 'School Supervisor' THEN 1 END) AS SchoolSupervisor,
    FROM participant_registration
    GROUP BY p_id
) pr
    ON pr.p_id = ra.p_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        training_id,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(file_id) > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS evidence
    FROM review_files
    GROUP BY training_id
) rf
    ON rf.training_id = ra.c_id
ORDER BY
    t.c_id DESC;
```

Note that this also fixes another problem your query had, which was that you were selecting many columns which did not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Under this refactor, there is nothing wrong with your current select, because the aggregation take place in a separate subquery.

Comment: thanks for the reply but the query gave me error: MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'file_id' in 'field list'

Comment: @MuhammadKhurshid I edited my answer, and it should work now without errors.

Comment: file_id is from review_files AS rf

Comment: I know, reload your page and check the updated answer.

Comment: query is executed but the values are incorrect, it shows me Mentors = 1 AND SchoolSupervisor = 0, while it should display Mentors = 13 & SS = 5.

Comment: Please edit your question and include sample data for all tables, neatly formatted as text tables.  Without seeing your data, and I can't make an update.

Comment: i have added snapshot of the DB please check it out. actually if a user have single evidence file (file_id) it shows correct values in mentors & SS, but if file_id count is > 1 (means if user have 2 files in review_files table) it will SUM the values of Mentors & SS twice

Comment: Sorry...I had a `GROUP BY` clause in my answer, which didn't belong there.  Try the updated answer.  If that still does not give you the expected results, then I am out of ideas.  Your data screenshot does not help much.

Comment: Thnx for the helping, i really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to the WHERE part of your query

```
AND pr.p_id IS NOT NULL AND rf.training_id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a group by pr.p_id to remove the duplicate records there. Since, the group by on `pr` is not present as of now, there might be multiple records of same p_id for same `ra`

```
group by t.c_id, ra.c_id, pr.p_id order by t.c_id desc
```